# Select Nested Field Value along with other fields using nest in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using .net nest library for querying elastic search, I have some nested fields along with others.

I would like to get the specific nested value as shown in the image below, I get correct Name, Title, UrlId but not the CategoryNames Value in "en"?

[image]

Comment: Can you share whole query which you are building with NEST?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible with [Source Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) to include only a specific value from a collection of nested types.

It should be possible to get that value with [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/script-fields-usage.html) though.